# please i'm new users of ros and i don't understand this probleme can you help me

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'chapter2_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(chapter2_tutorials)
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at chapter2_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:189 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    src/example1_b.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: /home/home/dev/catkin_ws/build
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Erreur 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221177/please-i%27m-new-users-of-ros-and-i-don%27t-understand-this-probleme--can-you-help-me/) by [bleuscreen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25123/bleuscreen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error is telling you that there isn't a file named `exaple1_b.cpp` in the `src` directory in the `chapter2_tutorials` package.

Does that file exist?

It looks like you're following a tutorial or working from a textbook; it would be helpful if you included a link to it in your question.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-11-19**:
Please, in future, also provide a more meaningful question title and more information in your question. Not just the pure error message.